# Como abrir uma página (documento) quando tudo estiver renderizado pelo browser?

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>index2</title>
    <style>
        
        iframe {
            width: 300px;
            height: 210px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima o documento contém vários vídeos incorporados dentro das tags `iframe` do *YouTube* o problema é que quando o documento é executado no *Browser* os `iframe` é carregado um por um e acaba deixando o usuário ver esses elementos sendo carregados. O que eu gostaria era que neste atraso em que o *Browser* não renderizou ainda todos os `iframe`, a mostrasse alguma imagem ou qualquer outra coisa e depois a mostrasse os `iframe`. Se possível gostaria de saber como se chama essa técnica que os programadores usam. Eu não sei se essa técnica é feira do lado do cliente ou do lado do servidor, mas se for um dos dois toda ajuda é bem, vinda!

**Notem**: Recomendo vocês abrir esse código de cima em um documento no próprio computador de vocês, eu acho que o *stack overflow* não permite incorporação de certos arquivos e um exemplo de um site que usa essa técnica é o [MEGA](https://mega.nz/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você, pode usar o `document.readyState` para poder verificar se a página tem o status como `complete` ou seja se o conteúdo da página foi carregado por completo.

**Exemplo**

Nós, queremos exibir um fundo com um texto de *Loading* enquanto os arquivos do site estão sendo carregados, quando estiverem carregados queremos remover da tela o fundo junto com o texto de *Loading*, assim exibindo os `<iframe>` que estão incorporando os vídeos do `YouTube`.

1. Primeiro, crie uma `<div>` com `id="loading"` e com conteúdo `Loading`:

   ```
   <div id="loading">Loading</div>
   ```
2. Depois, adicione alguns estilos para o nosso `#loading`, isso vai servir para ele ocupar 100% da tela, ficar centralizado, etc.

   ```
   #loading {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background: black;
       color: #ff7b00;
       font-family: arial;
       font-size: 30px;
       position: absolute;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
   }
   ```
3. Enseguida, para o `#loading` ficar com a altura 100% é necessário o seu pai também estar 100%, então adicione algo assim:

   ```
   html, body {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
   }
   ```
4. É **importante**, você fazer quando o conteúdo estourar para fora do `body` que ele fique oculto:

   ```
   body {
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```
5. Por último, podemos trabalhar com um código *JavaScript* bem simples:

   ```
   let loading = document.querySelector("#loading");
   let body = document.body;

   let checkLoading = setInterval(() => {
       if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
           clearInterval(checkLoading);

           body.removeChild(loading);
           body.style.overflow = "auto";
       }
   }, 100);
   ```

Bom, basicamente o código de cima vai verificar a cada `100` milissegundo se o conteúdo foi carregado, caso o conteúdo for carregado ele vai remover aquela `<div id="loading">` que criamos e vai adicionar ao `body` a propriedade `overflow` com o valor `auto` para poder voltar o scroll da página.

**Resultado**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>index2</title>
    <style>
        
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 300px;
            height: 210px;
        }

        #loading {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: black;
            color: #ff7b00;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="loading">Loading</div>

    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <script>
        let loading = document.querySelector("#loading");
        let body = document.body;

        let checkLoading = setInterval(() => {
            if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                clearInterval(checkLoading);
                
                body.removeChild(loading);
                body.style.overflow = "auto";
            }
        }, 100);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Nota:** Como você disse o *stackoverflow* não permite incorporação de conteúdo de terceiros.

**Alguns sites que poderão te ajudar:** [varvy](https://varvy.com/performance/document-ready-state.html), [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).

Answer (score 1):

Use o evento `window.onload`. Esse evento é chamado quando tudo tiver sido carregado.

Pode criar uma div fixa com uma mensagem "Carregando..." no centro da tela e no CSS colocar `visibility: hidden` nos iframes. Quando a página for aberta irá exibir a mensagem e quando todos os iframes forem carregados irá alterar a visibilidade dos iframes para `visible`.

> CSS

```
iframe {
   width: 300px;
   height: 210px;
   visibility: hidden;
}

#loader{
   display: flex;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div id="loader">
   Carregando...
</div>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="967" height="544" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZWVVzA-Yq8U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

> JS

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

      document.getElementById("loader").outerHTML = '';
      var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

      for(var i of iframes) i.style.visibility = "visible";

}
</script>
```

Comment: No meu `browser`, não funcionou! no `console` dispara à cada carregamento de um `iframe` um alerta com a mensagem `[Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.`

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na resposta. Essa mensagem que aparece no console do navegador é gerada pelo código do Youtube.